# Queue migration from one EMX Server to Other

Tags: java, websphere, connection-pooling, tibco-ems

We need advice on this queue migration topic.

There are two JMS providers (PROVIDER and NEWPROVIDER ) to connect to two instances of EMX. Each has some queues. Now we want to move all queues from PROVIDER to NEWPROVIDER at EMX side. At WebSphere admin console, minimum effort solution is to change the URL and authentication of PROVIDER to be same as NEWPROVIDER .

I don’t see any immediate issue as it may only seem to impact connection pool, max connection etc, but not sure to take changes to Production.

**Question**: Is there any issue in this approach or we should delete and recreate all queues under NEWPROVIDER.

To help understand this change faster I have created a diagram. Blue color shows current state, Red shows changes and to be state.

We are using WebSphere6.1/JMS(EMX)/Oracle.

[image: Queue Migration Diagram]

Comment: Given that it's the same target platform (EMX), why are there 2 JMS providers?

Comment: Not exactly same, they are different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Larry mentioned, it is quite straightforward. There was no question of any issue for in-flight messages etc. This is because it's handled by different team and not part of this question.

We are successfully managed to complete the task by changing URL and authentication details. We did not delete all queues and we did not recreate them in NEWPROVIDER. We just pointed PROVIDER to be same as NEWPROVIDER.

Answer (score 1):

Pointing WebSphere to the new EMS instance, as you've illustrated, is pretty straight-forward. The main question is: do all the relevant destinations (queues, topics, durable subscribers if any) exist on the new EMS instance? In other words, has the exact configuration been replicated from the existing EMS instance to the new instance? Will all WebSphere services have access to the data they require in order to operate with the new EMS instance? Will in-flight (undelivered/unacknowledged) messages that may live in queues on the old instance need to be available on the new instance?

If you're simply moving the store-files and conf files over, then all of this would essentially be taken care of.